# compare dates and add a column with previous transaction date

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have two dataframes: `df_a` containing a transaction date of interest between two parties id_a and id_b with a transaction id as tx_id and `df_b` containing all transactions between two parties along with their tx_id. I would like to add two more columns to df_a which capture the date of the transactions between both parties (id_a and id_b) immediately before the date of interest.

df_a can contain many transactions between the same parties and in each case the previous date of transaction needs to be added.

```
> df_a
        id_a    id_b    tx_id       date_of_interest
        2222    3189    1138312.0   2020-04-01 18:55:36.629318
        2222    3325    1138371.0   2020-04-01 19:15:33.341302
> df_b

    id_a    id_b    tx_id   date_all
    2222    3189    1045728 2020-02-13 00:18:18.840492
    2222    3189    1138312 2020-04-01 18:55:36.629318
    2222    3325    1052235 2020-02-17 19:56:07.809550
    2222    3325    1138371 2020-04-01 19:15:33.341302
```

Expected Output

```
> df_a
        id_a    id_b    tx_id       date                        prev_date.                  prev_tx_id
        2222    3189    1138312.0   2020-04-01 18:55:36.629318  2020-02-13 00:18:18.840492  1045728
        2222    3325    1138371.0   2020-04-01 19:15:33.341302  2020-02-17 19:56:07.809550 1052235
```

I was trying to use a groupby followed by iterating over each date but came up with nothing.

```
g = df_a.groupby(['id_a', 'id_b'])

prev_date = []
for name, group in g:
    # iterate through each date in g, 
    # prev_date_val = find the highest - 1 date in df_b dates for same id_a, id_b combinations
    # prev_date.append(prev_date_val)
```

Comment: the df_a.groupby function modifies the dataframe in place, meaning that is does not return a dataframe when you call it. Instead it changes the actual df_a in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.shift()` to shift the row down by one, then merge the dataframes together to get your date.

Small example here:

```py
>>> df_a = pd.DataFrame(dict(id_a=[1, 1], id_b=[2, 3], tx_id=[101, 111], date_of_interest=["18:55", "19:15"]))
>>> df_a
   id_a  id_b  tx_id date_of_interest
0     1     2    101            18:55
1     1     3    111            19:15
>>> df_b = pd.DataFrame(dict(id_a=[1, 1, 1, 1], id_b=[2, 2, 3, 3], tx_id=[100, 101, 110, 111], date_all=["00:18", "18:55", "19:00", "19:15"]))
>>> df_b
   id_a  id_b  tx_id date_all
0     1     2    100    00:18
1     1     2    101    18:55
2     1     3    110    19:00
3     1     3    111    19:15
```

Then

```py
>>> df_b_shifted = df_b.sort_values(["id_a", "id_b", "tx_id"]).shift()
>>> df_b_shifted.columns = [c+"_shift" for c in df_b.columns]  # Rename columns
>>> df_b_shifted
   id_a_shift  id_b_shift  tx_id_shift date_all_shift
0         NaN         NaN          NaN            NaN
1         1.0         2.0        100.0          00:18
2         1.0         2.0        101.0          18:55
3         1.0         3.0        110.0          19:00
>>> df_b_concat = pd.concat((df_b, df_b_shifted), axis=1)
>>> df_b_concat
   id_a  id_b  tx_id date_all  id_a_shift  id_b_shift  tx_id_shift date_all_shift
0     1     2    100    00:18         NaN         NaN          NaN            NaN
1     1     2    101    18:55         1.0         2.0        100.0          00:18
2     1     3    110    19:00         1.0         2.0        101.0          18:55
3     1     3    111    19:15         1.0         3.0        110.0          19:00
>>> df = df_b.merge(df_a, on=("id_a", "id_b", "tx_a"))
>>> # Keep only those that correspond to the same id_a, id_b
>>> df = df[(df.id_a==df.id_a_shift) & (df.id_b==df.id_b_shift)]
>>> res = df.drop(['date_all', 'id_a_shift', 'id_b_shift'], 1).rename(columns=dict(tx_id_shift="tx_id_prev", date_all_shift="prev_date"))
>>> res
   id_a  id_b  tx_id date_of_interest  tx_id_prev prev_date
0     1     2    101            18:55       100.0     00:18
1     1     3    111            19:15       110.0     19:00
```

Hope it helps ;)